# Most efficient way to add a (generated) header to many files?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.6

I'm working on a script which checks / creates / updates copyright notices at the top of source files in my project.

This is generally I/O bound because the header (missing or otherwise) tends to get bigger each time the script is used (e.g. adding more years to an existing notice), and so the rest of the file has to be relocated to a later offset. That means reading the whole file, and then writing it back (+ the small header changes I want).

It occurs to me that there is probably a more efficient way to do this. This use-case isn't so uncommon is it?

---

I fondly imagined that it might be possible to seek to a negative offset in the same way you can seek past the end of a file (which typically results in sparse files).

```
import os
fh = file("code.py", "rb+")
original_size = os.fstat( fh.fileno() ).st_size
data = fh.read()

# `prefix` should be prepended to the file
# `updated_data` is anchored to offset 0, and likely only a 
#    few 10s of bytes long (unlike the original file)
# `suffix should` be postpended to the file
prefix, updated_data, suffix = get_changes(data)

fh.seek(0)
fh.write(updated_data)

# WISHFUL THINKING. Not possible to seek to a negative offset.
fh.seek( -1 * len(prefix) )
fh.write(prefix)

fh.seek( max(original_size, len(updated_data)) )
fh.write(suffix)

fh.close()
```

Environmental stuff:

- Python v2.6
- GNU/Linux (Red Hat Enterprise 5 + Ubuntu 10.04 if it matters)

Comment: Instead of seeking to and fro, why can't you write the prefix first, followed by the updated_data followed by suffix?

Comment: No reason, I just wanted to illustrate how my data is structured. In production code I'd avoid unnecessary seeking as you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can seek to a negative index if you pass the *whence* argument to [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek), otherwise it's assumed to be absolute (so negative locations aren't allowed).

```
import os
f = open('insert.txt', 'r+')
f.seek(3)
f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR) # will go back one position
f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END) # one position before the end of the file
```

That won't really help you, though - writing bytes in the middle will overwrite the existing bytes, rather than shuffling everything forwards.

You could achieve what you want by reserving a fixed number of bytes of header at the start of the file - this is how binary file formats avoid having to write out whole files when they change. I wouldn't recommend it for source files, though. It would be pretty error-prone - if you got it wrong (or the header you wanted to write got too long) then the start of your code could be overwritten by the header-maintenance script.

A hybrid approach might work, though.

- The first time processing the files, write the header the slow way (writing out the whole file again), reserving some extra space for future growth, and put a sentinel at the end of the header. The sentinel should be something human-readable and easy not to break inadvertently.
- Then, next time you need to write the header, read the header in (up to the length you know you need). If the sentinel is in the right place you can use the fast overwrite technique.
- If not, you need to write the header the slow way again.

Some code (which doesn't handle the header size changing):

```
import sys
import os

RESERVED = 40
SENTINEL = '\n### HEADER ENDS ###\n'

def pad(heading):
    free_space = RESERVED - len(heading)
    padding = ('#' * free_space) if free_space > 0 else ''
    return heading + padding

def _write_header_slow(fname, text):
    # Do this in chunks instead if you have large files.
    dest = fname + '.temp'
    with open(fname) as infile:
        content = infile.read()
    with open(dest, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(text)
        outfile.write(SENTINEL)
        outfile.write(content)
    os.rename(dest, fname)

def write_header(fname, text):
    if not text.endswith('\n'):
        text += '\n'
    assert len(text) < RESERVED, 'too much for the header!'
    padded = pad(text)
    with open(fname, 'rb+') as f:
        current_header = f.read(RESERVED + len(SENTINEL))
        if current_header.endswith(SENTINEL):
            f.seek(0)
            print 'fast path!'
            f.write(padded)
        else:
            print 'slow path ):'
            _write_header_slow(fname, text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_header(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```